# Handling session id in php after logging in to change the menubar item from login to logout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, authentication

My webpage consists of a menubar, where there are five menus
 **HOME**, **DATA**, **FEEDBACK**, **ABOUT** & **LOGIN**.

1. My objective is to login from login menu(a jquery modal pops up for logging in) and after logging in I want the menubar to  be as 
   **HOME**, **DATA**, **FEEDBACK**, **ABOUT** and **LOGOUT**.
2. For this in the code below I have used  **if-else** condition *which shows login in if condition and logout in else condition.*
3. But the code is unable to recognize that I have logged in and always shows login only. How can I solve this

    *Thank you in advance*

`<?php include'connect.php';?
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.modal.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.modal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <style type="text/css" media="screen">
                html { background: transparent; }body   { font: normal 18px/1.6 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; color: #777; padding: 2em 5%; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff; } small { color: #aaa; }h1,h2,h3,h4 { color: #444; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.6em; letter-spacing: -1px; }  a { color: #0086B3; font-weight: 700; }     a:hover { color: #000; }    p code, li code {background:#ffffcc; color: #444; } pre { font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; } pre code { overflow: scroll; padding: 1em; border-radius: 10px; }  hr { height: 10px; background: #eee; border: none; } table {width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;} td { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 15px; }  td pre { margin: 0; } /* Example 2 (login form) */ .login_form.modal {border-radius: 0; line-height: 18px; padding: 0; font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;}
                .login_form h3 {margin: 0;padding: 10px;color: #fff;font-size: 14px;background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2e5764, #1e3d47);background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #1e3d47),color-stop(1, #2e5764));}
                .login_form.modal p { padding: 20px 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 0; background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #eee),color-stop(1, #fff)); overflow: hidden;}
                .login_form.modal p:last-child { border: none; }
                .login_form.modal p label { float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #333; font-size: 13px; width: 110px; line-height: 22px; }
                .login_form.modal p input[type="text"],
                .login_form.modal p input[type="password"] {font: normal 12px/18px "Lucida Grande", Verdana;padding: 3px;border: 1px solid #ddd;width: 200px;}
                .part {display: none;}`

```
    </head>
    <form action='submit' action='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' id='login-form' class='modal'></form>


                    <form   method='post'   class='login_form modal' id='ex2' style='display:none;'>
                        <h3>Please login to continue</h3>
                        <p><label>Username:</label><input type='text' name='username' /></p>
                        <p><label>Password:</label><input type='password' name='password' /></p>
                        <p><input type='submit' value='Login' class='btn btn-large btn-primary' /></p>
                    </form>
<div id='menu_wrapper'>
    `
    <div id='logo'>
        <img src="images/mdv.jpg" tab="MEDICAL DATA VISUALIZATION" height="96" width="67"> 
    </div>

    <div id='title'>
    <h style="font-size:30px;background-color:transparent;"><a style='color:white;background:transparent;' href='#'> MEDICAL DATA VISUALIZATION</h>
    <br>
    <h style="font-size:25px;background-color:transparent; color:none;">ONLINE MEDICAL DATA PROJECTION </a></h><br>
    </div>

<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
{?>
                    <div id='menu_wrapper'>
                        <div id='menu'>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='main.php'>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href='data.php'>Data</a></li>
                                <li><a   href='feedback.php'>Feedback</a></li>
                                <li><a href='about.php'>About</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#ex2' rel='modal:open'>LOGIN</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    //include'reg.php';
<?php
}
                    else 
{                   
?>  

                        <div id='menu_wrapper'>
                        <div id='menu'>
                            <ul><li><a href='songview.php'>Songs</a></li>
                                <li><a   href='feedback.php'>Feedback</a></li>
                                <li><a href='about.php'>About</a></li>";
                                ?><li> <a href='logout.php'>logout <?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
}
?>

<?php       
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']))
            {echo 'green';
                 //including config.php in our file
                $username = $_POST['username']; //Storing username in $username variable.
                $password = $_POST['password']; //Storing password in $password variable.
                echo 'test';
                    $query_run=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'");
                        $count=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                        echo $count;
                    if ($count == 0)
                    {                       
                    header("location:main.php");

                    }
                        else
                        {
                                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
                                if(!empty($row)) 
                                {           
                                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
                                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];                       
                        header("location:admin_panel.php");
                            }

                            ?> 
                            <?php

                        } 
        }
    }

    else
    {
        echo"death test";
    }
?>


<form action='submit' action='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' id='login-form' class='modal'></form>


                    <form   method='post'   class='login_form modal' id='ex2' style='display:none;'>
                        <h3>Please login to continue</h3>
                        <p><label>Username:</label><input type='text' name='username' /></p>
                        <p><label>Password:</label><input type='password' name='password' /></p>
                        <p><input type='submit' value='Login' class='btn btn-large btn-primary' /></p>
                    </form>
```

`

Comment: probably didn't call `session_start()` at the top

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your exact code, but what you posted here is missing a closing `</style>` right before your closing `</head>` tag

Comment: You also have a stray closing tag in your `else` statement. Remove the `"; ?>` after your `<li><a href='about.php'>About</a></li>` in the second menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
?>
                    <div id='menu_wrapper'>
                        <div id='menu'>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='main.php'>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href='data.php'>Data</a></li>
                                <li><a   href='feedback.php'>Feedback</a></li>
                                <li><a href='about.php'>About</a></li>
                                <li><a href='#ex2' rel='modal:open'>LOGIN</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    //include'reg.php';
<?php
}
                    else 
{                   
?>  

                        <div id='menu_wrapper'>
                        <div id='menu'>
                            <ul><li><a href='songview.php'>Songs</a></li>
                                <li><a   href='feedback.php'>Feedback</a></li>
                                <li><a href='about.php'>About</a></li>
                                <li> <a href='logout.php'>logout <?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?></a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```